# How many people can WebRTC support simultaneously with mesh topology?

Tags: webrtc

so my question is, how many people can WebRTC support simultaneously with mesh topology? for audio only, video only, audio&video

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054484/multi-party-webrtc-without-sfu

Comment: @user1390208 did you test what you have said in that question ?

Comment: read comments there

Comment: @user1390208 thanks